# AngularJS directive, Call service by directive attribute

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I'm trying to create an angular directive for calling service method to check changing database.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div my-directive="Panel.check"></div>
```

**What I'm want:**

Call "check" method of "Panel" service. Directive don't know anything about services and its method. It just parses attributes and binds them, Or if must be injected show me the solution.

**What I have:**

```
appDirectives.directive('myDirective', function($parse) {

var directiveOnObject = {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: { method:'&myDirective' },
    link: function(scope,element,attrs) {

        var panel = scope.method;

        console.log(panel());
    }
};  

return directiveOnObject;

});
```

Scope method should get instance of "Panel" and call "check" method of it.

Is there any solution to this? Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have access to the `Panel` service in the controller, for example:

```
angular.module('app').controller('Foo', function($scope, Panel) {
  $scope.Panel = Panel;
});
```

Now you can use your directive, but you when you pass a function with `&`, you need to put the parens as well:

```
<div my-directive="Panel.check()"></div>
```

Without it, it won't work. The rest of the code remains the same.

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wn6ok03JkIpyaXwHsy8D?p=preview)

EDIT: If you just need your directive to use one exact service or one exact method, inject the service into the directive like you did with `$parse` (which is not needed in any case by the way).

EDIT 2: If the service you want to call accepts parameter, you need to do something like:

```
<div my-directive="Panel.check(param1, param2)"></div>
```

Then in the directive, you need to map those parameters to your local objects, so if for example (inside your directive) you have:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  var foo = 1;
  var bar = 2;
}
```

And you want to pass those variables as parameters.

First, you need to recall how you named those parameters in the html, in concrete they were `param1` and `param2` so you need to do (inside the link function):

```
scope.method({param1: foo, param2: bar});
```

So for `param1` we pass `foo` and for `param2` we pass `bar`.

Comment: This is exactly what I want! thank you. But how about send parameters? How we can send parameters to factory from directive by this way?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need to inject the service in the directive :

```
appDirectives.directive('myDirective', ['$parse', 'myService', function($compile, myService){
 // here use 'myservice' to get access to variables and methods of the service
}]);
```